# Loading my built PHP modules failed with no error

Tags: php, module

I built my hello_world php module by following tihs: https://zando.io/post/hello-world-php-7-extension/

And I successfully built a hello.so under modules/

But when I tried to load this hello.so, it failed.

(adding `extension=hello.so` to php.ini and put the .so file to `extension_dir`)

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('hello'));
var_dump(hello_world());
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function hello_world() in /var/www/app/test.php(2) : eval()'d code:1 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/app/test.php(2): eval() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/app/test.php(2) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

But when I tried to load my friend's hello_world so file, it works!!

(same source code, same building process...)

I really don't know why...

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: Did you restart your server to load the extension?

Comment: @mastertje my code is same as the link: https://zando.io/post/hello-world-php-7-extension/

Comment: @kerbholz yes, I restart when I change every time

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

Because I use the wrong version of `phpize` and `php-config`.

The `phpinfo()` shows that `PHPAPI` is `20170718`

But my original phpize shows `20180731`

So I reinstall the `php7.2-dev`.

Then run `phpize7.2` and then `./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config7.2` to configure the settings.

And it works!